# How to get my paths correct for static files when using a reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I am passing this a reverse proxy for example mkteagle/admin will send me to mkteagle:8083. But it's like express can't find my static files at mkteagle:8083/dist/script.js. It loads up index.html fine just not the static files in the same folder.

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
// serve angular front end files from root path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
// Set our api routes
app.use('*/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});


/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '8082';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: Do you get some sort of error? I had a similar problem, having nginx as reverse proxy. The solution was to set a leading slash at the proxy. Like `proxy_pass http://mkteagle:8083/` - maybe this helps

Comment: I am just getting 404's for the static files. Node isn't throwing any errors. I tried setting the trailing slash. That didn't help but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Okay, but why not using nginx in the first place to serve static files?

Comment: Mostly because I am planning on running three different api's from this location. I was previously serving them up with node on my machine, but trying to get them ready for production. I don't mind serving up static files in nginx. It's just one more command to copy them over to a folder that nginx serves. I am just trying to go the easiest route. If I mess around with my server file, I only have to restart it.